# Do mitochondria use ATP in order make another ATP from glucose?

Tags: molecular-biology, metabolism, bioenergetics

Do mitochondria use ATP in order make another ATP from glucose, or does it use another source of energy to convert glucose to ATP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During ATP production through the citric acid cycle, some ATP is used to transport necessary molecules for the reactions.

- piruvate molecules are actively transported into the mitochondrial matrix [2]
- two NADH equivalents from glycolisis are transported into the mitochondrion and consume two molar equivalents ATP [1]
- protons leakage across the mitochondrial membrane leads to reduced ATP from NADH and FADH<sub>2</sub> [1]

In theory, one molar equivalent of glucose can generate 38 equivalents of ATP. The actual number is only 25 [1].

---

**References:**

1. Wikipedia contributors, "Citric acid cycle," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Citric_acid_cycle&oldid=610117265 (accessed June 26, 2014).
2. Wikipedia contributors, "Mitochondrion," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mitochondrion&oldid=614223751 (accessed June 26, 2014).